# How to activate qListWidget scrollbar for list with custom elements?

Tags: python, pyqt

I was working with the small desktop app and faced with a problem: I want to add QCheckBox instances into the QListWidget, but when I do this, the text from some of these checkboxes goes out of the window. I was trying to make line breaks in these checkboxes, but I faced the other problem - text is intersecting.

So, I decided to use a scroller, but it is not working if I simply use setHorizontalScrollBar, but it doesn't work, as I understood, because of my items are different widgets.
So, is it possible to let this horizontal scrollbar scroll the list with checkboxes?

I use PyQt with Python 3.8

[image: Example of the current situation]

Example of python code with adding elements to the ListWidget:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("updates_list.ui", self)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget {background: rgba(255,255,255,200)}")

        manga = ['Smth very long, line with a text, more long line with a text, even more long, and even more more \
            more long etc.', 'more text', 'even more text']
        for i in range(len(manga)):
            widget_manga = manga[i]
            box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(widget_manga)
            item = Qt.QListWidgetItem()
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, box)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Widget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Example of updates_list.ui file:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>783</width>
    <height>776</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <family>Ink Free</family>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QPushButton{
    color: #fe6637;
    background: #2a2a5c;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #fe6637;
}
QPushButton:hover{
    background: #5959a8;
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>550</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Fixedsys</family>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Выбор сайта</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>190</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>231</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Gabriola</family>
      <pointsize>26</pointsize>
      <weight>50</weight>
      <bold>false</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">
text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #fff, -2px 0 0 #fff, 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>ChapterSaver</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>111</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap>pixel_logo.png</pixmap>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>701</width>
      <height>511</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Joystix</family>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
     <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="autoScroll">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="dragDropOverwriteMode">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="dragDropMode">
     <enum>QAbstractItemView::NoDragDrop</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="selectionBehavior">
     <enum>QAbstractItemView::SelectItems</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="textElideMode">
     <enum>Qt::ElideLeft</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalScrollMode">
     <enum>QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerItem</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="viewMode">
     <enum>QListView::ListMode</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="modelColumn">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="currentRow">
     <number>-1</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>640</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Fixedsys</family>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Выбрать все</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>650</x>
      <y>640</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Fixedsys</family>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Удалить</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>260</x>
      <y>690</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Fixedsys</family>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Обновить</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting a widget for each item, and doing so doesn't make the item automatically larger if the embedded widget needs it (in fact, it's the item size hint that tries to resize the widget, if possible).

The direct solution to your issue is to set the size of the item based on the checkbox size *hint* (which is the preferred size the widget requests in order to display itself properly).

```
        for i in range(len(manga)):
            widget_manga = manga[i]
            box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(widget_manga)
            item = Qt.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setSizeHint(box.sizeHint())
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, box)
```

But, if you only want the items to be checkable, there's usually no need for that, as by default all items in a QListWidget can be checkable, you only need to *explicitly* set the initial state:

```
        for i in range(len(manga)):
            widget_manga = manga[i]
            item = Qt.QListWidgetItem(widget_manga)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, box)
```

If you need notifications about check state changes, connect to the [`itemChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemChanged) signal, which emits the item being modified, then verify its `checkState()` getter function, remembering that check states in Qt have three values: `Unchecked` (0), `PartiallyChecked` (1) and `Checked` (2).

Then, if you want to know all checked items, use that function in a for loop:

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.listWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.mangaItemChanged)

    def mangaItemChanged(self, changed):
        print('{} changed to {}'.format(
            changed.text(), changed.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        for i in range(self.listWidget.count()):
            item = self.listWidget.item(i)
            print(item.text(), item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

<sup>I see that you are using manual fixed geometries for all widgets in your UI; consider that this is discouraged for *a lot* of reasons, and [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) should be preferred instead.</sup>